# VSCode "you must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard'" but compiles fine

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I don't restart my computer often, and did this morning. When VSCode launched, it looks like it did an update and now the IDE is complaining about errors.

My application still compiles and runs fine, but in the IDE, I see 30k errors all saying something similar to the following:

```
'The type XXXXXX is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. [MyApp.Application]'
```

It looks like omnisharp is at the latest.

I am on a Mac as well.

Comment: What kind of project are you working on? .NET Framework, Standard, Core, ...? What SDK do you have installed locally? (`dotnet --version`)

Comment: I am running an asp.net core 3.1 app. SDK installed is the latest 3.1.402. The web project is not showing any errors, but all my other projects are.

Comment: Do you have a local mono installation? - if so, do [these instructions](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3990#issuecomment-675227919) help? VSCode also has an OmniSharp output (output window) which can have additional logs.

Comment: @MartinUllrich thanks so much! That worked great. Any idea why this happened all of the sudden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Martin Ullrich and for a good question to @Chris Kooken. I think it should be an approved answer in here for the next visitors to the page.

Following these [steps](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/3990#issuecomment-675227919) helped me to solve the issue:

```
 * Go to the VSCode settings (File > Preferences > Settings).
 * Search with the keywords omnisharp use global mono to locate the configuration.
 * Change the value to never from either auto or always.
 * REMEMBER to restart the VSCode to activate the change (I restarted it twice to be sure).
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the above mentioned setting in my `vscode` but what solved the same issue for me was enabling the following option: `Use Modern Net`

[image]

This makes sense since the error started appearing after upgrading the projects version from `.NET Core 3` to `.NET 7`